# Alphabet tree in Scala: finding resource

Tags: scala, tree

I'm trying to create a tree with one root and 26 leaf nodes being characters from the Alphabet. Are there any particular readings/resources out there that could help me learn more about tree structures in Scala?

Comment: Not really sure what you need the tree for. Is any tree OK? Or a binary tree? Or do you need a tree with higher branching factor (26, like for a trie)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
scala> abstract class Tree[A]
defined class Tree

scala> case class Node[A](children : List[Tree[A]]) extends Tree[A]
defined class Node

scala> case class Leaf[A](value : A) extends Tree[A]
defined class Leaf

scala> val root = Node(children = ('A' to 'Z') map (Leaf(_)) toList )
root: Node[Char] = Node(List(Leaf(A), Leaf(B), Leaf(C), Leaf(D), Leaf(E), Leaf(F), ...
```

Comment: Yes, quite so. Thank you for this sample, will denfinitely be useful for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is Huffman coding. Try the *Functional Programming Principles in Scala* course [here](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun). The assignment for week 4 in that course is [exactly](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-2012-001/assignment/view?assignment_id=15) what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Will definitely look though it